google maps apiでマーカーが消えない
Google MapのAPIを使って、検索バーに文字を打つとそこにマーカーが表示されるサイトを作ろうとしました。しかし、検索バーでマーカーを刺したあとに、再度別の場所を検索しようとしても、前回表示されたマーカーが消えません。
（例：ファミリーマートと検索したあとに、ローソンと検索しても、ファミリーマートのマーカーが残っている）
言語は、Typescriptとnext.jsを使ってます。
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MapWithMarkers: React.FC = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map>();
  const [placesService, setPlacesService] = useState<google.maps.places.PlacesService>();
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<google.maps.Marker[]>([]);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const googleMapScript = document.createElement('script');
        googleMapScript.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBdXNt3C6zl_ncZPNbM_eEEOYpmY9KGilo&libraries=places`;
    googleMapScript.async = true;
    window.document.body.appendChild(googleMapScript);

    googleMapScript.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const mapInstance = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') as HTMLElement, {
        center: { lat: 35, lng: 139 },
        zoom: 15,
      });
      setMap(mapInstance);
      setPlacesService(new window.google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapInstance));

      const input = document.getElementById('search') as HTMLInputElement;
      const searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', () => {
        const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length === 0) {
          return;
        }

        clearMarkers();

        const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(place => {
          if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log('Returned place contains no geometry');
            return;
          }

          const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            map: mapInstance,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location,
          });
          setMarkers(prevMarkers => [...prevMarkers, marker]);

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });

        mapInstance.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
    });

    return () => {
      window.document.body.removeChild(googleMapScript);
    };
  }, []);

  const clearMarkers = () => {
    markers.forEach(marker => {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="search"
        type="text"
        value={searchQuery}
        onChange={e => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="検索する場所を入力してください"
      />
      <div id="map" style={{ width: '100%', height: '400px'}}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapWithMarkers;


clearMarkersでマーカーを削除しようとしているのですが、markers.forEachの部分がうまく実行されません
試しに、
const clearMarkers = () => {
    console.log('clearMarkers');
    markers.forEach(marker => {
      console.log('clearing');
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
  };

として検索してみると、console.log('clearMarkers');は表示されますが、console.log('clearing');は表示されません。
原因がわかる方がいたら、教えてほしいです。
